# How to change button text in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How to change the button text when someone click on?

Code:

```
<Button disabled={this.state.disabled}
    type="primary"
    htmlType="submit"
    style={{
      background: '#ff9700',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      border: 'none',
      float: 'center',
    }}
    loading={this.state.loading}
    onClick={this.enterLoading}
    value="Next"
    id="buttontext"
    onClick="changeText()"
>
    Next 
</Button>
```

Comment: use a state variable for that, store the button text in a state variable and update the state using setState to change the button text.

Comment: @MayankShukla Could you please write code for button

Comment: check sample [working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/62830zpvxk).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Mayank is correct.

Create a variable called "text" (or whatever you choose) and put that instead of "Next".

```
state = {
  text: "Next"
}

changeText = (text) => {

  this.setState({ text }); 
} 
render() {
const { text } = this.state //destucture state
return (
  <Button 
     onClick={ () => { this.changeText("newtext")}  }> {text} </Button> )...etc
```

Note: this method will always change the text to "newtext" when you click. You can pass a variable there as well to make it more dynamic.

Hope this helps.

Update: Just saw Mayank comment. That code is essentially what I have. Just a tip you no longer need a constructor and you don't have to bind your methods anymore.

## Updated: React Hooks

Same thing but with the `useState` hook. Instead of calling the state variable `text`, I am using `buttonText` to be more explicit. The updated version would look like:

```
import { useState } from 'React';

const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("Next"); //same as creating your state variable where "Next" is the default value for buttonText and setButtonText is the setter function for your state variable instead of setState

const changeText = (text) => setButtonText(text);

return (
  <Button onClick={() => changeText("newText")}>{buttonText}</Button>
)
```

You can omit the `changeText` function all together and have this:

```
return (
    <Button onClick={() => setButtonText("newText")}>{buttonText}</Button>
)
```

## Updated: How to Add Set Timeout

Adding an update to answer a question in the comments: "If I wanted to use a setTimout to bring the button back to the previous text after 1 second where would I add that in?"

There are two ways that comes to mind: add the `setTimeout` to the `changeText` function or create an effect that depends on the `buttonText`.

**change text**

You can just pop the setTimeout right in this function.

Goes from this

```js
const changeText = (text) => setButtonText(text);
```

to this

```js
const initialState = "Next";
const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState(initialState); //same as creating your state variable where "Next" is the default value for buttonText and setButtonText is the setter function for your state variable instead of setState

const changeText = (text) => {
  setButtonText(text);
  setTimeout(() => setButtonText(initialState), [1000])
}
```

We add the `initialState` variable as a const to keep track of the "previous text". Since, it should never change we *could* define it in all caps snake case like `const INITIAL_STATE` meh your choice.

**useEffect**

We still need to define that `initialState` variable, again so we can keep track of the original. Then we can create a `useEffect` which is a React hook that allows you to "hook" into changes of a variable (that's only a part of `useEffect`, just enough to get us going here).

We can break the effect down into **two essential parts**: the body or **callback** of the effect, what do we want to do when the effect runs and the **dependency** or what triggers the effect to run. In this case, our callback will be `setTimeout` and set the button text inside that timeout and our `buttonText` will trigger the effect.

Here's the effect:

```js
useEffect(() => { 
  if(buttonText !== initialState){
    setTimeout(() => setButtonText(initialState), [1000])
  }
}, [buttonText])
```

Anytime the state variable `buttonText` changes this effect will run.
We start at

```js
buttonText = initialState // "Next"
```

the effect runs and checks the `if`. Since `buttonText` equals the initialState the conditions evaluates to `false` and we terminate the callback and the effect.

When the user clicks the button, `changeText` executes and sets the `buttonText` state which **updates** the variable triggering the effect. Now we run that `if` check again and this time it passes so we execute the `setTimeout`.

Inside the timeout we are setting state so the effect runs *again* and this time it fails because we just changed the state back to `initialState`.

> I recommend throwing a debugger in there or some logs to follow the trail

Long winded explanation. Here's what the whole component would look like using the effect approach.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const FancyButton = () => {
  const initialState = "Next";
  const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("Next"); //same as creating your state variable where "Next" is the default value for buttonText and setButtonText is the setter function for your state variable instead of setState

  // the effect
  useEffect(() => { 
    if(buttonText !== initialState){
      setTimeout(() => setButtonText(initialState), [1000])
    }
  }, [buttonText])

  const changeText = (text) => setButtonText(text);

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={() => changeText("newText")}>{buttonText}</button>
  )
};
```

> I added the `type` on the button because that's a good practice. And changed "Button" to "button". You can certainly have any component there you want, this works better for copying and pasting

Comment: If I wanted to use a setTimout to bring the button back to the previous text after 1 second where would I add that in?

Comment: Just seeing this  @krichey15. You can add the setTimeout in the `changeText` function.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Thank you. I'm new to react in general and this was clear and concise. If I could give more upvotes, I would. :D

Answer (score 1):

Where you wrote "Next", the button text, do this instead:

```
{this.state.disabled ? 'Disabled...' : 'Next'}
```

I this will display "Disabled..." when the state.disabled == true, and 'Next' when state.disabled == false.